# How to remove duplicates including the first instance and just include the unique non-repetitive nodes?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have the below sample XML code with me and the required output. I need to remove the duplicate rows, which is every instance. Can you help me how to achieve this using XSLT 2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <Company>Xyzz</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>223.33</Amount>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Company>Xyzz</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>223.33</Amount>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Company>Xyzz</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>223.33</Amount>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Company>pror</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>423.33</Amount>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Company>abcd</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>123.33</Amount>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Row>
        <Company>pror</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>423.33</Amount>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Company>abcd</Company>
        <Account>123567</Account>
        <Amount>123.33</Amount>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

Comment: Well, XSLT has `xsl:for-each-group` where you can then check inside whether `current-group()` has more than one item and ignore those groups. Will be a bit easier to express in XSLT 3 where you can use `composite="yes" group-by="*"` instead of `group-by="string-join(*, '|')"` or similar in XSLT 2 but give it a try and tell and show us exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for your advice on the Xslt2.0 logic. Can you let me know how we can achieve it in XSLT 3.0 because i never used 3.0 before. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping in XSLT 2 and 3 is done using `xsl:for-each-group` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-for-each-group), so `select="Row"` as the grouping population, decide which grouping key you want, if you want to use all child element values as a composite grouping key you use `xsl:for-each-group select="Row" composite="yes" group-by="*"` in XSLT 3; inside the `for-each-group` you then have access to the `current-group()` and can only output (or in generally process) its first and only item if there is only one item in the group by selecting `.[not(tail(current-group()))]` as `.` represents the first item in the group and `not(tail(current-group()))` will be true if there is no second item in the group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="Root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Row" composite="yes" group-by="*">
              <xsl:apply-templates select=".[not(tail(current-group()))]"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcj/